# Using JsPlumb on top of Dojox

Tags: jquery, dojo, jsplumb

Current version of JsPlumb is on top of Jquery, YUI or MooTools. I have a requirement where I need to write adapter for connecting jsPlumb with Dojo gfx.

I checked source code of [jsPlumb](https://github.com/sporritt/jsplumb/) , I found adapters for all three (Jquery,YUI and MooTools)

[Sample Adapter of Jquery, lists following details,](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb/blob/master/src/jquery.jsPlumb.js)

```
the library specific functions, such as find offset, get id, get attribute, extend etc.  
 * the full list is:
 * 
 * addClass             adds a class to the given element
 * animate              calls the underlying library's animate functionality
 * appendElement        appends a child element to a parent element.
 * bind                 binds some event to an element
 ...
 ...
```

Can somebody please point, how hard it is to replace all listed calls with dojo specific method calls? What do I need to consider while writing these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have written dojo adapter for jsPlumb  ( which works for most of the functionality), You can get source code at [github](https://github.com/bhosaledipak/JsPlumb_Dojo_Integreate)

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested to do a port of jsplumb to dojo. I dont even think a dojo's gfx comes into play here. It's mostly core functionality that needs porting. Sort of like most of the core functions in jquery (e.g. The common jquery $() functions).

Let me know if u are still interested, or have begun working on it. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, We have already started porting of jsPlumb to Dojo, Please visit https://github.com/bhosaledipak/JsPlumb_Dojo_Integreate